# Bootstrap confidence interval for mean

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, bootstrap, convergence

Take an iid sample $X_1,\dots,X_n$ from a distribution with (unknown) mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Let $\bar{X}_n^b$ be the bootstrap sample mean, and choose $R_n=R_n(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ s.t. $$C_n=\left\{y\in\mathbb R:\sqrt n\left(\bar{X}_n-y\right)\leq R_n\right\}$$
is a one-sided $1-\alpha$ confidence interval for $\bar{X}_n^b$. Show rigorously that $R_n$ converges in probability to $\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)$, where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the quantile function for $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

---

My end goal is to show that $C_n$ is asymptotically a $1-\alpha$ confidence interval for $\mu$.

I know that $\sqrt n\left(\bar{X}_n^b-\bar{X}_n\right)$ converges in distribution to $N(0,\sigma^2)$ (in fact the convergence is a.s. uniform). So I think this should force $R_n$ to converge to $\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)$ a.s. I would however appreciate a more rigorous detailed argument.

Once I have that $R_n\to\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)$ in probability, then a Slutsky argument with $\frac{\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)}{R_n}\cdot\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}_n-\mu\right)$ finishes the job.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.